# Fail2ban for GLPI

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I wanted to know if someone else has the same problem as me or if someone were knowing how to debug it :

I'm currently searching how can I ban people who try to connect to my GLPI in order to protect it from bruteforcers. That's why I installed "Fail2ban" :

```
nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf

    [glpi]
    enabled = true
    filter = glpi
    port = http, https
    logpath = /var/www/glpi/files/_log/event.log
    maxretry = 3

nano /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/glpi.conf

    [INCLUDES]
    before = common.conf
    [Definition]
    failregex = Connexion échouée de \w+ depuis l\’IP <HOST>
    ignoreregex =

/etc/init.d/fail2ban restart
```

But, when I try to see which lines match with my regex with this command :

```
fail2ban-regex /var/www/glpi/files/_log/event.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/glpi.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/glpi.conf
```

I have no results (0 line matched).

Then, I decided to try this regex as ignoreregex :

```
nano /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/glpi.conf

    [INCLUDES]
    before = common.conf
    [Definition]
    failregex =
    ignoreregex = Connexion échouée de \w+ depuis l\’IP <HOST>
```

And I make the same command as above (**fail2ban-regex**). I have the 20 lines "ignored" [imo, that proves that my regex is OK].

Bye, curumo29.

```
P.S : The tag <HOST> is the same as (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+) which permits to get and block the IP address of the bruteforcer with iptables [this tag is mandatory by fail2ban]
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried to make the same thing on Debian 9 (While I was on Debian 8) and it worked...
If someone was knowing why it's not working atm on Debian 8, it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in:

```
failregex = Connexion échouée de \w+ depuis l\’IP <HOST>
```

You must instead use

```
failregex = Connexion échouée de \w+ depuis l\'IP <HOST>
```

(Use `'` instead of `’`)

You can use this to debug regex :

```
fail2ban-regex -D /var/www/glpi/files/_log/event.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/glpi.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/glpi.conf --print-all-missed
```